# Laravel Generate not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am running Sublime Test 2 in Windows 7 64-bit. I have installed (and re-installed many times) Laravel Generator and Laravel 4 Artisan. I have updated composer and all dependencies. But I cannot get it to work properly. If I press ctrl-shift-P and type 'laravel' I get a list of 11 Artisan options, then a list of 17 Generate options, 6 of which appear to be duplications, and then another list of 20 Artisan options. The first lot of Artisan options give WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified, the Generate options give [InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace.

The second batch of Artisan options do appear to work eg Laravel Artisan: Controller: Make gives a command line and if I type 'test' it creates a restful controller called test.php.

However, the more comprehensive resource generation remains unavailable to me.
Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Does it work if you invoke artisan generate command through command-line outside SublimeText ?

Comment: I tried **php artisan controller:make test** in gitbash and that worked

Comment: However **php artisan generate:controller test** produced the same error as within ST2

Comment: Have you installed Artisan package? http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=52928#p52928

Comment: Indeed I have, using package control - probably about a dozen times by now! And of course Laravel Generator itself. And tried changing the php.exe path in preferences. Didn't help so currently it's back to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you install this plugin first: https://github.com/laravelbook/laravel4-sublimetext-helper

And then you might want to do what is referred here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/pro-workflow-in-laravel-and-sublime-text/#comment-925470112

There are other Windows users that had difficulties with this, but seem to have resolved them.

Comment: Installed the above helper, having first installed aublimecodeintel, re-started ST2, run as administrator. I've also added the php.exe folder to the windows 7 environmental path but no change. In **laravelgenerator.sublime-settings**, the path now looks like this: **C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.3.8\\php.exe**

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `way/generators` package, you need to make sure to include the service provider (`'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'`) in your `config.app` file.